# How to assign a custom class to my ListView control?

Tags: c#

I have created a Windows Forms Application project, added a ListView control to it, and created a class named ListViewTest. Now I need to assign this class to my designed ListView control, so I can add more methods to it. How can I do that?

```
class ListViewTest
{

    public int getNumber()
    {
        return 12345;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the code in your questions, that you are talking about.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary a code for it. I just want to know how to assign a class to the designed ListView control. In MFC it's done easily by right-clicking a control, and choosing "Add class". But looks like there is no similar option in Visual C#.

Comment: what do you mean by assigning a class to the designed ListView?

Comment: I want to make my ListViewTest class to represent my ListView control that I've just designed. This way I will be able to call the getNumber() method using the ListView control itself.

Comment: You're not making any sense.  There's no such thing as "assigning this class to your designed ListView control" or "making your ListViewTest class represent your ListView control that you just designed". None of that actually means anything.  Are you saying that you want to create a custom ListView control that inherits all the existing ListView functionality and then adds some new functionality of your own?  If so then what you need to do is actually inherit the ListView class is your own class.  You can then add instances of your own class directly to a form.

Comment: jmcilhinney explains it well. You can inherit from the real ListView: `class ListViewTest : ListView` and after compiling it you will find the new class in the toolbox and you can add it to your form. - Or maybe you want to build a kind of 'helper' class that works with ListViews? You need to give it a public reference to its listview and set this eg in the form constructor..